# Benefit of using entangled photons over classically correlated source for ghost imaging

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics

I have found a paper([See this](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.93.093602)) which talks about the comparison of classically correlated source and an entangled photon source (generated by Spontaneous Parametric Down Conversion)for ghost imaging. I've found that classically correlated source can be used for ghost imaging but an entangled photon source provides much better visibility of the image in low photon regime. Although, I want to understand the entire math behind it, I am unable to do so as the calculations are complicated. I found that $G(x_1, x_2) \propto \langle n(q)\rangle^2$ for classically correlated source and $G(x_1, x_2) \propto \langle n(q)\rangle + \langle n(q)\rangle^2$ in case of entangled source where $G(x_1,x_2)$ is the correlation function and $\langle n(q)\rangle$ is the mean number of photons. Finally, Visibility is given by
\begin{equation} 
V = \frac{G(x_1, x_2)}{\langle I(x_1)I(x_2) \rangle}
\end{equation}
So in a low photon regime, visibility of entangled source is better for ghost imaging but in case of high photon regime, both have similar visibility. The calculations they did to get the expression for $G(x_1, x_2)$ are a bit complicated for my level. Some reference to any other similar review article or a simple answer would be really helpful